# In R-studio I want to know how I would save a loop result without deleting the previous loop result

Tags: r, static, normal-distribution, nested-for-loop

In this code I want to calculate the trimmed mean and variance of trimmed mean for normal distribution in many value of alpha ( I want to calculate the value of the each alpha from 1 to 13 ) and storage the result in the data.frame then print the all result But the problem is that the new result storages over the previous result and at the end i end up getting only the last result of alpha value.

```
ProDistFun<- data.frame(matrix(nrow=91, ncol=4))
colnames(ProDistFun)<-c("x","Alpha","Trimmed Mean","Variance Of Trimmed Mean")
mu=7    # Mean Value
sigma2=4   # Variance value
for (alpha in c(0.001,0.01,0.025,0.05,0.1,0.25,0.375))
{
for(i in 1:13)
{
ProDistFun[i,1]<-i
ProDistFun[i,2]<-alpha
# The trimmed mean
a=qnorm(alpha, mean=mu, sd=sqrt(sigma2))
b=qnorm(1-alpha, mean=mu, sd=sqrt(sigma2))
fun_TM <- function(x) ((x*exp(-0.5*((x-mu)/sqrt(sigma2))^2))/((1-2*alpha)*(sqrt(2*pi*sigma2))))
MT1 <- integrate(fun_TM, a, b)
MT <-MT1$value
ProDistFun[i,3]<-MT
# The variance of trimmed mean
fun_VTM <- function(x) ((((x-MT)^2)*exp(-0.5*((x-mu)/sqrt(sigma2))^2))/(sqrt(2*pi*sigma2)))
fVTM <- integrate(fun_VTM, a, b)
fV <- fVTM$value
VT=((fV+(alpha*(a-MT)^2)+(alpha*(b-MT)^2))/((1-2*alpha)^2))
ProDistFun[i,4]<-VT
}
}
print(ProDistFun)
```

Comment: What is the inner for loop for?  Why 1 to 13?

Comment: Better description of the issues. At the moment the problem is very unclear. The code does not throw any errors. TRUE, the output look incorrect, but asking us to look at your code and figure out what each of steps are supposed to do is not a reasonable expectation. (And if you are expecting to recover meaningful data from a nested for loop than you should be using the two loop indices at the same assignment at some point or another. I don't see that happening.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited Sept 30 12:23 hours**

It's still not totally clear to me what you're trying to accomplish with x since you use it in confusing ways, but using most of your code and simplifying drastically but still using a `for loop`

Create an empty dataframe without the matrix contortions.

```r
ProDistFun <- data.frame(
   x = integer(0), 
   Alpha = numeric(0), 
   Trimmed_Mean = numeric(0), 
   Variance_Of_Trimmed_Mean = numeric(0)
   )
```

Assign your two constants.  **IMPORTANT NOTE** -- throughout your code please stop treating assignment `<-` as the same thing as `=` it will cause problems down the road.

```r
mu <- 7    # Mean Value
sigma2 <- 4   # Variance value
```

Pull your two functions out of the loops (no point in rerunning them every iteration).  I have no idea if they are correct but they seem to work. It also seems to me that in these functions you want the x value to be the value of `i` so I've made that change.  If you don't you get 13 iterations of identical

```r
fun_TM <- function(x) {
   ((i*exp(-0.5*((i-mu)/sqrt(sigma2))^2))/((1-2*alpha)*(sqrt(2*pi*sigma2))))
}

fun_VTM <- function(x) {
   ((((i-MT)^2)*exp(-0.5*((i-mu)/sqrt(sigma2))^2))/(sqrt(2*pi*sigma2)))
}
```

Now we run the nested loops of `alpha` and `i`.  We build a row to add to our empty dataframe `ProDist_df` and then last step is `rbind` the `newrow` to it.  Note as stated in the help file for `integrate` we need to `Vectorize`.

```r
for (alpha in c(0.001,0.01,0.025,0.05,0.1,0.25,0.375)) {
   for (i in 1:13) {
      a <- qnorm(alpha, mean = mu, sd = sqrt(sigma2))
      b <- qnorm(1 - alpha, mean = mu, sd = sqrt(sigma2))
      MT1 <- integrate(Vectorize(fun_TM), a, b)
      MT <- MT1$value
      fVTM <- integrate(Vectorize(fun_VTM), a, b)
      fV <- fVTM$value
      VT <- ((fV+(alpha*(a-MT)^2)+(alpha*(b-MT)^2))/((1-2*alpha)^2))
      newrow <- data.frame(x = i, 
                           Alpha = alpha, 
                           Trimmed_Mean = MT, 
                           Variance_Of_Trimmed_Mean = VT)
      ProDist_df <- rbind(ProDist_df, newrow)
   }
}

ProDist_df
#>     x Alpha Trimmed_Mean Variance_Of_Trimmed_Mean
#> 1   1 0.001   0.02744577                0.2003378
#> 2   2 0.001   0.21710028                0.5148306
#> 3   3 0.001   1.00307392                1.4849135
#> 4   4 0.001   3.20833233                0.6092747
#> 5   5 0.001   7.49244239                9.4048587
#> 6   6 0.001  13.08172721              109.7134117
#> 7   7 0.001  17.29412878              262.6203021
#> 8   8 0.001  17.44230295              195.0733274
#> 9   9 0.001  13.48639629               30.3828344
#> 10 10 0.001   8.02083083                3.2269398
#> 11 11 0.001   3.67793771               18.0605860
#> 12 12 0.001   1.30260169               12.5886402
#> 13 13 0.001   0.35679506                4.5613376
#> 14  1 0.010   0.02104086                1.4856627
#> 15  2 0.010   0.16643643                1.7087503
#> 16  3 0.010   0.76899043                2.5612272
#> 17  4 0.010   2.45961619                2.3689151
#> 18  5 0.010   5.74396001                1.1324626
#> 19  6 0.010  10.02889499               28.3270524
#> 20  7 0.010  13.25826466               76.9619814
#> 21  8 0.010  13.37185999               50.5144290
#> 22  9 0.010  10.33912801                2.7851234
#> 23 10 0.010   6.14904048                9.7709433
#> 24 11 0.010   2.81963158               18.3179999
#> 25 12 0.010   0.99861856               11.4783190
#> 26 13 0.010   0.27353117                4.8704116
#> 27  1 0.025   0.01828687                3.5703608
#> 28  2 0.025   0.14465195                3.7170106
#> 29  3 0.025   0.66833905                4.3472611
#> 30  4 0.025   2.13768272                4.1121498
#> 31  5 0.025   4.99214637                1.0747081
#> 32  6 0.025   8.71623613               12.2965566
#> 33  7 0.025  11.52292107               37.4315915
#> 34  8 0.025  11.62164818               22.0916831
#> 35  9 0.025   8.98586347                1.0699878
#> 36 10 0.025   5.34420680               13.1972079
#> 37 11 0.025   2.45057652               19.1385400
#> 38 12 0.025   0.86791169               12.3691446
#> 39 13 0.025   0.23772931                6.5199633
#> 40  1 0.050   0.01619943                7.3749079
#> 41  2 0.050   0.12813995                7.4154400
#> 42  3 0.050   0.59204825                7.6768541
#> 43  4 0.050   1.89366655                6.8889173
#> 44  5 0.050   4.42229360                2.4843697
#> 45  6 0.050   7.72127906                5.6367092
#> 46  7 0.050  10.20758133               19.2763445
#> 47  8 0.050  10.29503875               10.2078727
#> 48  9 0.050   7.96012848                2.5125393
#> 49 10 0.050   4.73416638               16.5558668
#> 50 11 0.050   2.17084357               21.3087060
#> 51 12 0.050   0.76883970               15.1092609
#> 52 13 0.050   0.21059254                9.9710784
#> 53  1 0.100   0.01419911               17.3206584
#> 54  2 0.100   0.11231710               17.1281634
#> 55  3 0.100   0.51894156               16.5102647
#> 56  4 0.100   1.65983477               13.8052303
#> 57  5 0.100   3.87622451                6.3261279
#> 58  6 0.100   6.76784806                2.9011142
#> 59  7 0.100   8.94713932                9.2952208
#> 60  8 0.100   9.02379741                4.8107658
#> 61  9 0.100   6.97720412                6.0182204
#> 62 10 0.100   4.14958694               22.3456468
#> 63 11 0.100   1.90278571               28.0669010
#> 64 12 0.100   0.67390263               23.5641219
#> 65 13 0.100   0.18458837               19.4835253
#> 66  1 0.250   0.01195695              101.3283283
#> 67  2 0.250   0.09458127               99.3524957
#> 68  3 0.250   0.43699624               91.6992768
#> 69  4 0.250   1.39773265               71.1428700
#> 70  5 0.250   3.26413547               35.4870897
#> 71  6 0.250   5.69914690                7.1958771
#> 72  7 0.250   7.53430941                4.8250199
#> 73  8 0.250   7.59886254                4.6624497
#> 74  9 0.250   5.87544385               18.9156520
#> 75 10 0.250   3.49433163               57.7975362
#> 76 11 0.250   1.60231955               87.6386891
#> 77 12 0.250   0.56748763               98.7559156
#> 78 13 0.250   0.15544029              101.2808652
#> 79  1 0.375   0.01129729              591.0212507
#> 80  2 0.375   0.08936330              578.6087319
#> 81  3 0.375   0.41288753              529.2387893
#> 82  4 0.375   1.32062094              401.4184815
#> 83  5 0.375   3.08405591              197.9457725
#> 84  6 0.375   5.38472985               37.5416149
#> 85  7 0.375   7.11864801                5.0996822
#> 86  8 0.375   7.17963979                7.6766516
#> 87  9 0.375   5.55130064               59.4024907
#> 88 10 0.375   3.30155234              228.2708772
#> 89 11 0.375   1.51392096              415.5768786
#> 90 12 0.375   0.53617983              529.7332481
#> 91 13 0.375   0.14686478              575.9244272
```

Comment: I want to calculate the value of the each alpha from 1 to 13

Comment: 1 to 13 what?  The way your formula are constructed x does **NOT** cause anything to change.  Do you just want the same answer repeated 13 times?

Answer (score 0):

The general way to save all atomic values generated in a loop is to create an empty vector before the loop and then append the new values to the vector inside the loop. E.g.,

```
output <- vector()
for (i in 1:5) {
      newvalue <- i
      output <- c(output, newvalue)
}
```